# JBehave web: going for Web Runner or Selenium?

Tags: selenium, bdd, jbehave

I am new to BDD and JBehave. I am developing a web app and I am not sure whether to choose:

- **JBehave + Web Runner** *or*
- **JBehave + Selenium**

Are they complementary or should I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a reply to my question on a mailing list. I thought I would share it on SO. Here is it:

> WebRunner is a web front-end to run generic stories, be they web-based
>   or not.    It's got nothing to do with Selenium.
>
> If you're developing a webapp, go with Selenium, but choose the
>   WebDriver API (aka Selenium 2.x).
>
> A tutorial to get you started:
>   https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial/tree/master/etsy-selenium